# how to use $filter in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, filter, ionic2, migrating

I'm migrating an Ionic App to Ionic 2 App, since I'm not expert on Ionic 2 I got some problems doing it.

My question now is if there is any function like $filter in Ionic 2.

This is the code from Ionic 1 that I need to convert:

```
 var group = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
                var dateObj = new Date(orders[i].DocumentDate);

                var date = $filter('date')(dateObj, 'dd-MM-yyyy');

                dateObj = new Date(orders[i].EDIMessageDate);
                orders[i].time = $filter('date')(dateObj, 'HH:mm');

                if (angular.isDefined(group[date])) {

                    group[date].push(orders[i]);
                } else {
                    group[date] = [orders[i]]
                }
            }
```

So far I have done this:

```
let group = {};
  for(let  i = 0; i<orders.length; i++){

      let dateObj = new Date(orders[i].DocumentDate);
      let date = $filter('date')(dateObj, 'dd-MM-yyy');

      dateObj = new Date(orders[i].EDIMessageDate);
      orders[i].time = $filter('date')(dateObj, 'HH:mm');

      if(group[date] != null)
          group[date].push(orders[i]);
      else
          group[date] = [orders[i]];

  }
```

But I don't know how I can replace:

```
$filter('date')(dateObj, 'dd-MM-yyy');
```

To Ionic 2.
Any advice?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options here.

**Option 1:** You can use [**momentjs**](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/)

**Option 2:** You can use Angular [**DatePipe**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html#!#sts=Pipe).

```
{{yourDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Comment: Yep, you can format date on the html template using datepipe.

Comment: So I guess I have to go with momentjs since I need it in code to form a group of orders of the same day...

Comment: Yep, That is the best option in your use case.Let me know if you have any issue with that approach.

Comment: I think it's good now...
If I got any other problem I will reply...
Thank you a lot for the help!

Comment: It's pleasure :)